# Raise requested

Tags: raise

Our company restructured our pay scale (in a good way). But I'm now at the bottom of the scale for the specific job description as they didn't adjust my pay.

New employees coming in are being paid between $10,000 and $12,500 more than I am.  I requested a raise in May and was told I had to wait until my review.  I had my review in June and was told I needed to wait until the budget was set. That was Sept 1st.  On Sept 12th I asked my boss if anything was agreed on.  She said she requested and recommended me for a raise but it 'has not been approved'.  She didn't say it wouldn't be, but 'has not been approved' gives me nothing to go on. She also didn't let me know when she requested it, so I don't know how long I should wait.  I feel like I've waited long enough.

I didn't want to push it because my boss was 9 months pregnant and getting ready to go on leave and I knew she had so much work to get done before she left. I didn't want to add to her stress.  She is on leave now.

Do I wait? Do I talk to her boss (who I'm reporting to)?  I've been there 25 years and feel so undervalued.  Knowing all these new people are coming in making  25% more than I am is upsetting.  I definitely deserve it.  If I left now, they would really have a hard time keeping all the programs I handle running.  Thoughts?

Comment: **If I left now, they would really have a hard time keeping all the programs I handle running.** - Don't fool yourself. If they wanted to get rid of you they'd do it in a heartbeat. If it were me, I'd take it to your current acting manager. Explain the history of your conversations, but don't mention anything about the other employees being paid more for the same role/work.

Comment: Who is handling her responsibilities while she is on maternity leave for the weeks and months she will be out of the office? You probably should have ask, when the budget would be approved, before she left.

Comment: "**New employees coming in are being paid between $10,000 and $12,500 more than I am**". Do they have more experiences or specialized skills than you ? Or do they work in the similar roles as you do ?

Answer (score 3):

Waiting / doing nothing is always only benefit the employer, not you. Nothing changes on its own, especially after 25 years.

You may be seen as complacent employee that will not leave even if not 100% happy.

It comes down to how much do you want this particular job

If you been there for so long, most likely you can get better offer somewhere else.

I would suggest getting resume ready and test the water, search for your skillset and apply for jobs you find attractive.

If / when you get an offer, negotiate up to your desired compensation level, given you haven't left your current employment, and then make a decision if to stay at your current position, demanding a matching compensation or leave for new and better employment.